# call an executable string from python

Tags: python, shell, executable

I'm trying to find a way to run an executable script that can be downloaded from the web from Python, without saving it as a file.  The script can be python code or bash or whatever - it should execute appropriately based on the shebang.  I.e. if the following were saved in a file called `script`, then I want something that will run `./script` without needing to save the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from my_module import *

scoped_hash = sys.argv[1]
print(scoped_hash)
```

I have a function that reads such a file from the web and attempts to execute it:

```
def execute_artifact(command_string):
    os.system('sh | ' + command_string)
```

Here's what happens when I call it:

```
>>> print(string)
'#!/usr/bin/env python3\nimport sys\nfrom my_module import *\n\nscoped_hash = sys.argv[1]\n\nobject_string = read_artifact(scoped_hash)\nparsed_object = parse_object(object_string)\nprint(parsed_object)\n'
>>> execute_artifact(string) 
sh-3.2$ Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-57 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-10 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
Usage: import [options ...] [ file ]
```

Bizarrely, ImageMagick is called.  I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: why do you think `sh` will execute Python source code??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I guess because of the shebang telling it to interpret the code as python.

Comment: OK, I wrote an answer assuming it was Python always. You want to dynamically execute some text based on the shebang line. Looking around, it seems like the *kernel* handles the shebang on linux. Note sure if there is any great ways to do this without using a file other than parsing the shebang yourself and manually invoking the appropriate interpreter. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/850384/is-there-a-command-for-running-a-script-according-to-its-shebang-line

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'd be interested in seeing your answer assuming it's python, if you wouldn't mind posting that as an answer

Comment: Ok, I un-deleted it

Comment: What's the reason for not saving to file? Saving to file, marking it executable, and passing it to subprocess seems like a pythonic approach to me.

Comment: @Jesusaur.  What's saving or not saving a file have to do with being Pythonic?

Comment: @DavidJ. it's simple and practical way to rely on existing libraries.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This answer was added before OP updated requirements to include:

> The script can be python code or bash or whatever - it should execute appropriately based on the shebang.

Some may still find the below helpful if they decided to try to parse the shebang themselves:

Probably, the sanest way to do this is to pass the string to the `python` interpreter as standard input:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["python"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(command_string.encode())
```

My instinct tells me this entire thing is fraught with pitfalls. Perhaps, at least, you want to launch it using the same executable that launched your current process, so:

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(command_string.encode())
```

If you want to use arguments, I think using the `-c` option to pass in code as a string as an argument works, then you have access to the rest, so:

```
import subprocess
import sys

command_string = """
import sys
print(f"{sys.argv=}")
"""

completed_process = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", command_string, "foo", "bar", "baz"])
```

The above prints:

```
sys.argv=['-c', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: How would I pass the input?  I tried this `    p.communicate(command_string.encode(), 'alkwjefwfj')`. and it returned an error origininating in subprocess.py.

Comment: @DavidJ. why are you passing `'alkwjefwfj'`??? That's being passed as the `timeout` parameter... You just need `p.communicate(command_string.encode())` where `command_string` is your string... (it needs to be encoded to bytes but that's it)

Comment: `command_string.encode()` is a string of python code that expects an argument (it includes `sys.argv`.  I'm wondering how this argument can be passed.

Comment: @DavidJ. hmm, found a way using the `-c` option, where you pass a string of python statements to be executed. Note sure if it's the best approach but it seems to work

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done in full generality.

If you want the shebang line to be interpreted as usual, you must write the script to a file. This is a hard requirement of the protocol that makes shebangs work. When a script with a shebang line is executed by the operating system, the kernel (and yes, it’s not the shell which does it, unlike what the question implies) reads the script and invokes the interpreter specified in the shebang, passing the pathname of the script as a command line argument. For that mechanism to work, the script must exist in the file system where the interpreter can find it. (It’s a rather fragile design, leading to [some security issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/348263), but it is what it is.)

Many interpreters will allow you to specify the program text on standard input or on the command line, but it is nowhere guaranteed that it will work for any interpreter. If you know you are working with an interpreter which can do it, you can simply try to parse the shebang line yourself and invoke the interpreter manually:

```python
import io
import subprocess
import re

_RE_SHBANG = re.compile(br'^#!\s*(\S+)(?:\s+(.*))?\s*\n$')

def execute(script_body):
    stream = io.BytesIO(script_body)
    shebang = stream.readline()
    m = _RE_SHBANG.match(shebang)
    if not m:
        # not a shebang
        raise ValueError(shebang)
    interp, arg = m.groups()
    arg = (arg,) if arg is not None else ()
    return subprocess.call([interp, *arg, '-c', script_body])
```

The above will work for POSIX shell and Python scripts, but not e.g. for Perl, node.js or standalone Lua scripts, as the respective interpreters take the `-e` option instead of `-c` (and the latter doesn’t even ignore shebangs in code given on the command line, so that needs to be separately stripped too). Feeding the script to the interpreter through standard input is also possible, but considerably more involved, and will prevent the script itself from using the standard input stream. That is also possible to overcome, but it doesn’t change the fact that it’s just a makeshift workaround that isn’t anywhere guaranteed to work in the first place. Better to simply write the script to a file anyway.